# What does this error mean? "recon-source: no matching clause for syntax: (quote-syntax srcloc)"

Tags: racket

I got this message when I clicked on the Stepper in Racket Intermediete Student with Lambda. Further, it said: caused by the expression in annotate.rkt, line 134, column 13.

Never seen this before! There is nothing in my code that caused it, as far as I can make out.

What does this mean and what triggers such a message? What can I do about it?

Comment: That's a bug. Could you report the bug along with a code that results in this error at https://github.com/racket/htdp/issues/new? Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks! Will do as you suggest.